# Changing behavior of jQuery Validation plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-validate

I've been reading the documentation of a [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)

 and for some reason I couldn't find a way to change the behavior

I'm trying to get it to color the input's background in red, instead of writing 
anything.. is there perhaps a similar plugin that does that already?

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but you can do that from scratch in like only 5 lines of jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **highlight** and **unhighlight**

```
highlight: function (element, errorClass) {                
            $(element).css({ "background-color": BackgroundColour });
        },

unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
            $(element).css({ "background-color": "#FFFFFF" });                
        }
```

These can be added just below rules

Answer (score 0):

You can control anything in the Validation plugin. Search in the [API](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) for a callback method called `showErrors`. You can use it to customize error rendering